# Spring Data ElasticSearch - How to ignore discovered node

Tags: spring, connection, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm developing a service using ElasticSearch.

My ElasticSearch has 3 nodes and which has clustered by private IPs.

My local computer is not in the same private IP area (ie., I have to connect using public IP).

I'm trying to connect the master node using public IP.

Here is the context configuration for ElasticsearchTemplate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.my.project"/>

    <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="my_public_ip:9300" />

    <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

However, ElasticsearchTemplate(of Spring data elasticsearch) automatically discover clustered node and failed to connect because of the private IPs.

Is there any way to ignore other discovered nodes for development or test?

I've attached error logs below.

Thanks in advance.

```
2014-01-03 18:57:55 [DEBUG] Log4jESLogger.java::internalDebug:109 - [Moonstar, Danielle] failed to connect to discovered node [[My_ES_Node02][***********][inet[/172.27.123.123:9300]]{rack_id=rack05, max_local_storage_nodes=1, zone=zone01}]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [My_ES_Node02][inet[/172.27.123.123:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:693)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:590)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:451)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:294)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:162)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.buildClient(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(TransportClientFactoryBean.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the iptables rules of the system (assuming linux), as it will by default block your elasticsearch ports(9200/9300). If possible turn it off.

Are u able to telnet localhost at 9300 and 9200 from your instance ?

Check the elasticsearch logs for any misconfiguration.

you can also separate the dev/prod/test environment.

you need to change cluster name configuration

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html

once you have separate clusters just specify them into cluster-name parameter as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

   <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.my.project"/>

   <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-name="cluster-name" cluster-nodes="my_public_ip:9300" />

   <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client"/>
</bean>
```